# Converting values in a df column to True/False

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I am trying to replace all stocks in the "Is in SP100?" with true or false. So far I have the false working , but not sure how to get the program to say for any variable that exists in that column, return True:

```
newmerge.replace([np.var=='', np.nan], [True, False])


        Company         Weight      IsinSP100?
Symbol          
AAPL    Apple Inc.      3.699828    AAPL
MSFT    Microsoft       2.686835    MSFT
AMZN    Amazon.com Inc. 1.901109    AMZN
AN      AutoNation Inc. 0.013148    False
NWS    News Corporation 0.007284    False
```

This is a column in another df with all the stocks that ARE in the SP100, but it doesn't work when I put it in the replace function :

```
Wiki100Data['SP100']
```

My expected output would be all stocks with variables in the "is in SP500" column to be "True", and stocks without variables in the column to return "False".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['IsinSP100?'] = df.index.isin(Wiki100Data['SP100'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this to convert your current column to True or False:

```
df['IsinSP100?'].ne('False')
```